# Is it possible to return elements from a function?

Tags: function, return

I was just wondering if it was possible to create an element like int i in a function, use it in the function code and then return it from outside.
the code would resemble this:

```
int testFunc(int i){
    i++;
}
 return i;// <-- can I do this?
```

If this is NOT possible, would anyone perhaps know how to return a value from a function? Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: What language? C?

Comment: @MichaelAlbers Yes

Comment: Please show more code. Where is the outer `i` defined and how is it related to the other one?

Comment: "If this is NOT possible, would anyone perhaps know how to do this?" Do what exactly? Please describe what you actually need to achieve.

Comment: @Thilo in the parameter.

Comment: what I was asking for is how would you return an element from a function.

Comment: The parameter signature only defines local variables for the function body. Those are not visible from outside.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this @Thilo

Answer (score 2):

I would make the variable a global

```
int i;

void testFunc(){
   i++;
}

int anotherFunc(){
  return i;
}
```